# How to set title for UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Please, how can I  programmatically  set same title, which is on my picture? On picture is `UITabBarController` and there I can simple set title and picture on storyboard. But I added on `myUITableViewController` a `UIToolbar` with a image. Here is picture, what I want:

[image]

I want to the little title under `UIBarButtonItem` in `UIToolbar`. And here is my code of `UIToolbar`. When I want to setTitle for `UIBarButtonItem`, nothing happened...

```
UIBarButtonItem *studentClassButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"children-1.pgn"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(studentAction:)];
[studentClassButton setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:studentClassButton, nil];

[self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Comment: The image name may be children-1.PNG not .pgn, this will not give u error or warning, and u will not be able to see image

Comment: Uhm It's strange. It's really a mistake, but toolbar looks ok :O.

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` does not support having both a title and an image. You need to create a custom view with both and then create the `UIBarButtonItem` from the custom view.